# Django: How do i filter to return only those candidates that have paid >=10000

Tags: python, django-filter

Here is my model.py

```
 class Candidate(models.Model):
            person = models.OneToOneField(
                Person, related_name='person_candidate', on_delete=models.PROTECT)

            def __str__(self):
                return str(self.person)

            @property
            def total_candidate_votes(self):
                return self.candidate_votes.filter(candidate=self).count()

            @property
            def amount_paid(self):
                return self.candidate_payments.aggregate(models.Sum('fees'))['fees__sum'] or 0

            @property
            def is_qualified_to_vie(self):
                return self.amount_paid >= 10000
```

Help me create a filter that will show candidates who have only paid >=10000
          Filter.py

```
class CandidateFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='iexact', name='person__first_name')
    is_qualified_to_vie = django_filters.BooleanFilter(method='filter_by_qualified_candidates')

    def filter_by_qualified_candidates(self, queryset, field, value):
        return queryset.filter
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that python properties can't be translated into django filter expressions. I'd recommend using custom queryset methods in addition to the python properties here. Something like the below:

```py
class CandidateQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def annotate_amount_paid(self):
        return self.annotate(amount_paid=models.Sum('candidate_payments__fees'))

    def qualified_to_vie(self, yes=True):
        # eg, Candidate.objects.qualified_to_vie()
        qs = return self.annotate_amount_paid()
        if yes:
            return qs.filter(amount_paid__gte=10000)
        return qs.filter(amount_paid__lt=10000)


class Candidate(models.Model):
    ...

    objects = CandidateQuerySet.as_manager()
```

From here, it's fairly straightforward.

```py
class CandidateFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    is_qualified_to_vie = django_filters.BooleanFilter(method='filter_by_qualified_candidates')

    def filter_by_qualified_candidates(self, queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.qualified_to_vie(value)
```

Note that the above is just the gist of the idea and will probably require some changes in order to actually function.